# How to store scaled image in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, canvas

I'm creating one drawing app, there I have option to zoom in/out of the canvas image which I have drawn using drawImage() method, after zoom the image I am trying to save the image using toDataUrl() method but its showing blank page after assigning width and height of zoomed image to canvas.
 Below code is to save the image after zoomed

```
destinationCanvas.width = 500;              // actual size given with integer values
destinationCanvas.height = 500;
 destinationCanvas.style.width = '500px';     // show at 50% on screen
destinationCanvas.style.height = '500px';

 var destinationCanvasURL = destinationCanvas.toDataURL();  
 console.log("markerNormalStyleChange() destinationCanvasURL - "+destinationCanvasURL);

function drawImage(_onScreenMarkingImagePath) {
 var canvas = document.getElementById('drawOnScreen');
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 var imageObject = new Image();
 var div = $('#drawOnScreenContext'),
 w = $(window).width() - 1,
 h = $(window).height() - 150;

 canvas.width = w;  
 canvas.height = h ;  

$(imageObject).load(function () {
    ctx.drawImage(imageObject, 0, 0, w,h);

});

}
```

Below code is for rawing and zooming the image, here after draw on canvas if I try to zoom then drawn contents will removed because its drawing image only, so for zooming I want to zoom drawn contents also

```
var requestID;
(function() {
var root = this; //global object

var ImgTouchCanvas = function(options) {
    if( !options || !options.canvas || !options.path) {
        throw 'ImgZoom constructor: missing arguments canvas or path';
    }

    this.canvas         = options.canvas;
    this.canvas.width   = this.canvas.clientWidth;
    this.canvas.height  = this.canvas.clientHeight;
    this.context        = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    console.log("ImgTouchCanvas() initiated this.canvas.width - "+this.canvas.width);
    console.log("ImgTouchCanvas() initiated this.canvas.height - "+this.canvas.height);

    this.desktop = options.desktop || false; //non touch events

    this.position = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
    this.scale = {
        x: 0.5,
        y: 0.5
    };
    this.imgTexture = new Image();
    this.imgTexture.src = options.path;

    this.lastZoomScale = null;
    this.lastX = null;
    this.lastY = null;

    this.init = false;
    this.checkRequestAnimationFrame();
    requestID = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));

    this.setEventListeners();
};


ImgTouchCanvas.prototype = {
    animate: function() {
        console.log("ImgTouchCanvas requestAnimationFrame()");
        //set scale such as image cover all the canvas
        if(!this.init) {
            if(this.imgTexture.width) {
                var scaleRatio = null;
                if(this.canvas.clientWidth > this.canvas.clientHeight) {
                    scaleRatio = this.canvas.clientWidth / this.imgTexture.width;
                }
                else {
                    scaleRatio = this.canvas.clientHeight / this.imgTexture.height;
                }

                this.scale.x = scaleRatio;  
                this.scale.y = scaleRatio;
                this.init = true;
            }
        }

        //this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

        //canvas.width = w;    
        //canvas.height = h ;  
        /*this.canvas.width   = zoomWidth;
        this.canvas.height  = zoomHeight;*/

        this.context.drawImage(
            this.imgTexture, 
            this.position.x, this.position.y, 
            this.scale.x * this.imgTexture.width, 
            this.scale.y * this.imgTexture.height);



        console.log("this.scale.x * this.imgTexture.width -- "+this.scale.x * this.imgTexture.width);
        console.log("this.scale.y * this.imgTexture.height -- "+this.scale.y * this.imgTexture.height);

        mWidth = this.scale.x * this.imgTexture.width;
        mHeight = this.scale.y * this.imgTexture.height;

        console.log("mWidth  -- "+mWidth);
        console.log("mHeight  -- "+mHeight);

        //if($('#pinchZoomInZoomOut').find('#pinchZoomInZoomOutBg').hasClass('btnIconHighLight')) {
            //requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
        //}else{
            //cancelAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
        //}  

    },


    gesturePinchZoom: function(event) {
        var zoom = false;

        if( event.targetTouches.length >= 2 ) {
            var p1 = event.targetTouches[0];
            var p2 = event.targetTouches[1];
            var zoomScale = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p2.pageX - p1.pageX, 2) + Math.pow(p2.pageY - p1.pageY, 2)); //euclidian distance

            if( this.lastZoomScale ) {
                zoom = zoomScale - this.lastZoomScale;
            }

            this.lastZoomScale = zoomScale;
        }    

        return zoom;
    },

    doZoom: function(zoom) {
        if(!zoom) return;

        //new scale
        var currentScale = this.scale.x;
        var newScale = this.scale.x + zoom/100;


        //some helpers
        var deltaScale = newScale - currentScale;
        var currentWidth    = (this.imgTexture.width * this.scale.x);
        var currentHeight   = (this.imgTexture.height * this.scale.y);
        var deltaWidth  = this.imgTexture.width*deltaScale;
        var deltaHeight = this.imgTexture.height*deltaScale;


        //by default scale doesnt change position and only add/remove pixel to right and bottom
        //so we must move the image to the left to keep the image centered
        //ex: coefX and coefY = 0.5 when image is centered <=> move image to the left 0.5x pixels added to the right
        var canvasmiddleX = this.canvas.clientWidth / 2;
        var canvasmiddleY = this.canvas.clientHeight / 2;
        var xonmap = (-this.position.x) + canvasmiddleX;
        var yonmap = (-this.position.y) + canvasmiddleY;
        var coefX = -xonmap / (currentWidth);
        var coefY = -yonmap / (currentHeight);
        var newPosX = this.position.x + deltaWidth*coefX;
        var newPosY = this.position.y + deltaHeight*coefY;

        //edges cases
        var newWidth = currentWidth + deltaWidth;
        var newHeight = currentHeight + deltaHeight;
        zoomWidth = newWidth;
        zoomHeight = newHeight;
        //console.log("doZoom() newWidth -- "+newWidth);
        //console.log("doZoom() newHeight -- "+newHeight);


        if( newWidth < this.canvas.clientWidth ) return;
        if( newPosX > 0 ) { newPosX = 0; }
        if( newPosX + newWidth < this.canvas.clientWidth ) { newPosX = this.canvas.clientWidth - newWidth;}

        if( newHeight < this.canvas.clientHeight ) return;
        if( newPosY > 0 ) { newPosY = 0; }
        if( newPosY + newHeight < this.canvas.clientHeight ) { newPosY = this.canvas.clientHeight - newHeight; }


        //finally affectations
        this.scale.x    = newScale;
        this.scale.y    = newScale;
        this.position.x = newPosX;
        this.position.y = newPosY;
    },  

    doMove: function(relativeX, relativeY) {
        if(this.lastX && this.lastY) {
          var deltaX = relativeX - this.lastX;
          var deltaY = relativeY - this.lastY;
          var currentWidth = (this.imgTexture.width * this.scale.x);
          var currentHeight = (this.imgTexture.height * this.scale.y);

          //console.log("doZoom() currentWidth -- "+currentWidth);
          //console.log("doZoom() currentHeight -- "+currentHeight);

          this.position.x += deltaX;
          this.position.y += deltaY;


          //edge cases
          if( this.position.x > 0 ) {
            this.position.x = 0;
          }
          else if( this.position.x + currentWidth < this.canvas.clientWidth ) {
            this.position.x = this.canvas.clientWidth - currentWidth;
          }
          if( this.position.y > 0 ) {
            this.position.y = 0;
          }
          else if( this.position.y + currentHeight < this.canvas.clientHeight ) {
            this.position.y = this.canvas.clientHeight - currentHeight;
          }
        }

        this.lastX = relativeX;
        this.lastY = relativeY;
    },

    Draw222: function(x, y, isDown) {
        //console.log("Draw222() -- "+isDown);
         if (isDown) {  
             this.context.beginPath();
             this.context.strokeStyle="#FF0000";
             this.context.lineWidth = 5;
             this.context.lineJoin = "round";
             this.context.moveTo(lx, ly);
             this.context.lineTo(x, y);
             this.context.closePath();
             this.context.stroke();
            }
            lx = x; ly = y;
    },

    setEventListeners: function() {
        // touch
        this.canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
            this.lastX          = null;
            this.lastY          = null;
            this.lastZoomScale  = null;
            //newCtx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
            var relativeX = e.targetTouches[0].pageX - this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
            var relativeY = e.targetTouches[0].pageY - this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;    

            if($('#pinchZoomInZoomOut').find('#pinchZoomInZoomOutBg').hasClass('btnIconHighLight')) {
                //requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
            }else{
                $( '#undoIcon' ).css({
                    opacity: 1,
                    pointerEvents: 'auto'
                });

                cancelAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
                canvasPressed = true;
                this.Draw222(parseInt(relativeX), parseInt(relativeY), false);
            } 

        }.bind(this));

        this.canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if(e.targetTouches.length == 2 && $('#pinchZoomInZoomOut').find('#pinchZoomInZoomOutBg').hasClass('btnIconHighLight')) { //pinch
                console.log("pinch zoom")  
                requestID = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
                this.doZoom(this.gesturePinchZoom(e));
            }
            else {
                //console.log("touchmove  --- 1")
                var relativeX = e.targetTouches[0].pageX - this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
                var relativeY = e.targetTouches[0].pageY - this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;                

                if($('#pinchZoomInZoomOut').find('#pinchZoomInZoomOutBg').hasClass('btnIconHighLight')) {
                    //console.log("hasClass  btnIconHighLight --- ");

                    requestID = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
                    this.doMove(relativeX, relativeY);
                }else{
                    //console.log("touchmove  --- canvasPressed -- "+canvasPressed)
                    if (canvasPressed) {
                        cancelAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
                        this.Draw222(parseInt(relativeX), parseInt(relativeY), true);
                    }
                } 
            }
        }.bind(this));

        this.canvas.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //cPush();
            canvasPressed = false;

            /*var base64String = null;

            var canvas = document.getElementById('drawOnScreen');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            // save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
            console.log("dataURL - "+dataURL);*/
            //base64ByteString = dataURL;
            //dataURL = dataURL.substr(dataURL.lastIndexOf(',') + 1);

        }.bind(this));
    },

    checkRequestAnimationFrame: function() {
        var lastTime = 0;
        var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
        for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
            window.cancelAnimationFrame = 
              window[vendors[x]+'CancelAnimationFrame'] || window[vendors[x]+'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
        }

        if (!window.requestAnimationFrame) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
                var currTime = new Date().getTime();
                var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
                var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); }, 
                  timeToCall);
                lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
                return id;
            };
        }

        if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame) {
            window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
                clearTimeout(id);
            };
        }
    }
};

root.ImgTouchCanvas = ImgTouchCanvas;
}).call(this);
```

And for pinch zoom in/out the image, I am using this https://github.com/rombdn/img-touch-canvas

Comment: Is `destinationCanvas` the original canvas on which you've drawn ? setting either `width`or `height` properties of a canvas does clear its context completely, so you'd need to redraw the image after having done so.

Comment: @Kaiido  See actually I am zooming image on the canvas from 600x600 to 1200x1200 and then Same image im trying to copy into destination canvas with 1200x1200 size only BUT its not copying entire image.. its only copying canvas size only

Comment: We don't see how you are drawing this image on the destination canvas in your code block. It should be `destinationCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(theImage, 0,0,destinationCanvas.width, destinationCanvas.height)`;

Comment: @Kaiido please check I have added drawImage method.. Same canvas Im using for drawImage.. What I am trying actually drawing on canvas after zoom also

Comment: The second code block doesn't seem to be relevant. Is the first one how you really wrote it ? If so, you are calling `toDataURL` before having drawn anything on the canvas.

Comment: after drawing on canvas also I m checking with toDatUrl but its showing blank screen only